# Gaussian 16 fchk and log file import in mathematica

Tags: import, physics, chemistry

I am working with Gaussian log files and fchk files imported into Mathematica and I noticed a few things.

The ExampleData in documentation for these files use Gaussian 03 output files, while the current version is Gaussian 16. I wonder if there has been any change in data output between versions.[fchk link](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/format/FCHK.html) and [log file import](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/format/GaussianLog.html)

The .log file for a geometry optimization job also contains thermodynamics data, heat capacity, entropy, and if polar keyword is chosen, polarizability, hyperpolarizability, etc. None of the two import options .fchk or .log capture this additional information.
Are there plans to increase the import capabilities, or is there a workaround to capture at least the thermodynamic data from Gaussian output?

Thank you,

Comment: "I wonder if there has been any change in data output between versions" - this would be better answered by Gaussian, rather than here. Also, note that this is a forum of volunteers NOT linked to Wolfram Research directly, although some Wolfram employees do frequent the forum. You may want to direct the question to Wolfram support instead: they are probably in a better position to know whether there are plans to increase the Gaussian file import capabilities.

Comment: @bhopshang - please do file a report [here](https://www.wolfram.com/support/contact/?topic=Feedback) with your suggestion. It would also be helpful to provide the fchk file in question and a description of what you would like to import from it.